Nest.js can nott resolve dependencies
I have a project called Bifrost with root.module.ts and in this project I'm using a lib called auth-module that I created with a friend.
root.module.ts from the Bifrost project:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CacheModule } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import type { RedisClientOptions } from 'redis';
import { redisStore } from 'cache-manager-redis-yet';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { LoggerModule } from 'nestjs-pino';
import { CameraModule } from '../camera/camera.module';
import { HealthcheckModule } from '../healthcheck/healthcheck.module';
import { ExampleModule } from '../example/example.module';
import { AuthModule } from '../auth/auth.module';
import { AuthModule as ExternalAuthModule } from '@eusouagabriel/auth-module';
import { UserModule } from '../users/user.module';
import { ThirdPartyAppModule } from '../thirdPartyApps/thirdPartyApp.module';
import configuration from '../config/configuration';
import pino from 'pino';
import { PlateRegistryModule } from '../plateRegistry/plateRegistry.module';
import { OcrModule } from '../ocr/ocr.module';
import { SimCardModule } from '../simCard/simCard.module';
import { validate } from '@/validators/env.validation';
import { RouterModule } from '../router/router.module';
import { MqttAuthModule } from '../mqttAuth/mqttAuth.module';
import { AddressModule } from '../address/address.module';
import { InstallationModule } from '../installation/installation.module';
import { SurveillanceModule } from '../surveillance/surveillance.module';
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { ProvisioningModule } from '../provisioning/provisioning.module';
import { SalesOperationsModule } from '../salesOperations/salesOperations.module';
import { BullBoardModule } from '@bull-board/nestjs';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@bull-board/express';
import { BullBoardAuthMiddleware } from './middlewares/bullBoardAuth.middleware';
import { DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS } from '@/constants/time.constants';
import { TutkModule } from '../tutk/tutk.module';
import { BffLegacyProvisioningModule } from '../bff/legacyProvisioning/bffLegacyProvisioning.module';
import { InstallationTermModule } from '../installationTerm/installationTerm.module';
import { BffProvisioningModule } from '../bff/Provisioning/bffProvisioning.module';
import { AirtableModule } from '../airtable/airtable.module';
import { ImageModule } from '../images/images.module';
import { NotificationModule } from '../notification/notification.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      validate: validate,
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [configuration],
    }),
    CacheModule.registerAsync<RedisClientOptions>({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const host = configService.get<string>('REDIS_HOST');
        const port = configService.get<number>('REDIS_PORT');
        const url = `redis://${host}:${port}`;
        const database = configService.get<number>('REDIS_DB');
        return {
          store: redisStore,
          url,
          database,
          ttl: 1 * DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS, // default TimeToLive (TTL)
        };
      },
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    BullModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        redis: {
          db: configService.get<number>('REDIS_DB'),
          host: configService.get('REDIS_HOST'),
          port: configService.get('REDIS_PORT'),
        },
      }),
    }),
    BullBoardModule.forRoot({
      route: '/queues',
      adapter: ExpressAdapter,
      middleware: BullBoardAuthMiddleware,
    }),
    LoggerModule.forRoot({
      forRoutes: [
        'addresses',
        'auth/*',
        'bff/*',
        'cameras',
        'installationTerms',
        'examples/*',
        'installations',
        'ocr/*',
        'provisioning/*',
        'routers',
        'sim-cards',
        'surveillance/*',
        'third-party-applications',
        'users',
        'images/*',
        'notification',
        'sales-operations',
      ],
      pinoHttp: {
        logger: pino({
          formatters: {
            level: (label, number) => {
              return { level: number, status: label };
            },
          },
          redact: ['req.headers.authorization', 'req.headers.cookie'],
        }),
      },
    }),
    CameraModule,
    HealthcheckModule,
    ExampleModule,
    AuthModule,
    ExternalAuthModule,
    UserModule,
    ThirdPartyAppModule,
    OcrModule,
    PlateRegistryModule,
    SimCardModule,
    RouterModule, // Note: It is not the @nestjs/core Router Module!
    MqttAuthModule,
    AddressModule,
    InstallationModule,
    SurveillanceModule,
    ProvisioningModule,
    SalesOperationsModule,
    BffLegacyProvisioningModule,
    BffProvisioningModule,
    AirtableModule,
    TutkModule,
    InstallationTermModule,
    ImageModule,
    NotificationModule,
  ],
})
export class RootModule {}

auth.module.ts (from the auth-module lib):
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtStrategy } from './strategies/jwtAuth.strategy';
import { ApplicationLoginService } from './login/applicationLoginService';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [PassportModule, ConfigModule],
  providers: [JwtStrategy, ApplicationLoginService],
  exports: [JwtStrategy, ApplicationLoginService],
})
export class AuthModule {}

jwtAuth.strategy.ts (also a file from the lib):
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { JwtPayloadDto } from './dtos/jwtPayload.dto';
import { AuthenticatedEntity } from '../decorators/authenticatedEntity.decorator';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as jwksRsa from 'jwks-rsa';
import * as https from 'https';
import { firstLetterToUpperCase } from '../utils/string';
import { getAuthorizerUrl, getGabrielInternalCa } from '../utils/config';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    const issuerUrl = getAuthorizerUrl(configService);

    const ca = issuerUrl.endsWith('gabriel.internal')
      ? getGabrielInternalCa(configService)
      : undefined;

    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKeyProvider: jwksRsa.passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `${issuerUrl}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
        requestAgent: new https.Agent(ca ? { ca } : {}),
      }),
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: JwtPayloadDto) {
    const authenticatedEntity: AuthenticatedEntity = {
      id: payload.sub,
      type: firstLetterToUpperCase(payload.sub_type) as
        | 'User'
        | 'ThirdPartyApp',
      roles: payload.roles,
    };

    return authenticatedEntity;
  }
}

The error:
[Nest] 51840  - 09/10/2024, 9:02:21 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtStrategy (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AuthModule a valid NestJS module?
- If ConfigService is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
- If ConfigService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ConfigService */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtStrategy (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AuthModule a valid NestJS module?
- If ConfigService is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
- If ConfigService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ConfigService */ ]
  })

    at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:254:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Injector.resolveComponentInstance (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:207:33)
    at resolveParam (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:128:38)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:143:27)
    at Injector.loadInstance (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:70:13)
    at Injector.loadProvider (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:97:9)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:56:13
    at async Promise.all (index 3)

What am I doing wrong?
I tried several examples that I saw here and in the documentation

As you already have the ConfigModule set to global: true, what if you remove it from the AuthModule?

Are you sure that you are showing us the AuthModule with the issue? because you are using 2 AuthModule and if Im not wrong the error coming from the AuthModule of your project and not from the library
